# Cacheing in PHP code for plugin

Tags: plugin-development, cache

I have a plugin that makes several and potentially slow database calls that eventually return 8 Entries. Is there a way to make use of Craft's built in caching on the plugin side? Using the {% cache %} tag doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: Are you referring to caching from one of your plugin's templates or caching from PHP code?

Comment: Caching from PHP code. The plugin does not have a template, just returns a set of Entries from a variable.

Comment: Then Justin's [answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6585/57) is spot on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to take a look at the `CacheService` class which is the service that allows you to programmatically interact with the internal cache.

This is an example of how to set some cache that expires in 3600 seconds (one hour). Set the expiration to 0 if you never want it to expire.

```
craft()->cache->set('some_key', 'some_value', 3600);
```

Just checkout `CacheService` for more details, as there are more methods and parameters to make use of, but this should be the basic use case.

[CacheService Class Reference](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-cacheservice.html)